# Placing an integer unto a two dimension array (matrix)

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

Ok, so guys I'm trying to make a program in which you guess where your inputted number is placed randomly unto the matrix or two dimensional array.
For example the user inputted '3' and so the integer will be placed on a random row and column of the matrix.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define R 4
#define C 4
void display(char a[][C]);
void placing(char b[][C]);
void guess(int m, int n);

void main(){
int x=0,y=0,m,n,number;
int matrix[R][C];
char a[R][C]={{'x','x','x','x'},{'x','x','x','x'},{'x','x','x','x'},{'x','x','x','x'}};
printf("\t\t\t      Welcome to my game");
printf("\nEnter your number: ");
scanf("%d",&number);
display(a);
placing(a);
printf("\n\nYour number is now being placed at a random location");
printf("\n\nGuess where your number is located (row) (column)");
printf("\n\nEnter coordinates: ");
scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);

getch();
}

void display(char a[][C]){
for(int row=0; row<R; row++)
{
    printf ("\n");
    for(int column=0; column<C; column++)
    {
    printf ("\t%c\t", a[row][column]);
    }
}
}

void placing(int b[][C]){
int randomrow=0,randomcolumn=0;
int i=0;

randomrow = rand()%4;
randomcolumn = rand()%4;

for(int row=0; row < randomrow; row++){
    for(int column=0;column < randomcolumn; column++, i++){
        b[row][column];
    }
}
printf("%d",b[R][C]);
}
```

This is the whole program. any tips?

Comment: And also it's incomplete so the b[row][column] line is still missing of code.

Comment: How this program is different from "guess a one out of four numbers"? What does it have to do with matrices at all?

Comment: C++ _or_ C, pick one god damn it.

Comment: @Steven  Where is there the inputted number?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want... what would the other elements in the array be filled with? Do you want to have people guess two numbers and see if they were both correct instead of just one? What does the inputted number 3 have to do with it? Is the two dimensional array really necessary?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's not that different at all it's just using matrices since our teacher told us to do like a board game in which we use matrix. And since snakes and ladder, tic tac toe is too mainstream and we shouldn't make it said our teacher so yeah.

Comment: @GillBates C, sorry

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oh right I should have also placed it in the function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int matrix[4][4] = 
    {
        {-1,-1,-1,-1},
        {-1,-1,-1,-1},
        {-1,-1,-1,-1},
        {-1,-1,-1,-1},
    };

    int user_input;
    int random_row;
    int random_column;
    int row_guess;
    int col_guess;

    printf("Enter a number to add: \n");
    scanf("%d", &user_input);
    printf("User entered: %d\n", user_input);

    srand(time(NULL)); 

    random_row = rand() % 4;
    random_column = rand() % 4;

    printf("random_row: %d\n", random_row);
    printf("random_column: %d\n", random_column);

    matrix[random_row][random_column] = user_input;

    for(int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
    {
        for(int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[row][column]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Guess Random Row: \n");
    scanf("%d", &row_guess);
    printf("User Row Guess: %d\n", row_guess);

    printf("Guess Random Column: \n");

    scanf("%d", &col_guess);
    printf("User Column Guess: %d\n", col_guess);

    if (matrix[row_guess][col_guess] == user_input)
    {
        printf("You guessed correctly!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You guessed incorrectly\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1
my matrix is a char[4][4] which contains 16 x's. Is it possible to do the same given your code? or Am I just gonna place it as an integer? My code is at top I've edited it.

Comment: @Steven It is not important what type of elements is.

Comment: @Steven you need the call to srand(time(NULL)) for your rand() to give different values http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html